# Print functionality resetting other jQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to print a div content on click, I am able to print it but after print preview when I cancel, none of my jQuery events are working.

Why this is happening? I dont want to refresh the page after print preview

Here is my JS code for print

```
$('.btn li:nth-child(1) > a').on("click", function(e){  
    var divElements = document.getElementById("divContentId").innerHTML;
    var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = 
        "<html><head><title>Print Title</title></head><body><table width='670'><tr><td><h1>This is Print Preview Title</h1>" + divElements + "</td></tr></table></body>";
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
        window.close();
      return true;
    }, 250);
  $(".btn-options").hide(); // this is not firing after cancelling print preview event none of other events working
});
```

Comment: You should put the HTML to print inside an `iframe` and print there, not replace the current document.

Comment: That last `.hide()` line is executed immediately after the click, before the printing starts. You're also putting `<html>` and `<head>` into `<body>` (and not closing `<html>`)? The proper way is to a) change `<title>` b) use `document.body.innerHTML = "<table>...</table>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you could `print` inside an `iframe` instead :

```
$('.test').on("click", function() {
  var divElements = $("#divContentId").html();

  $('<iframe class="hidden" id="printer"></iframe>').appendTo('body');
  var printer = $('#printer');
  printer.contents().find('body').append("<table width='670'><tr><td><h1>This is Print Preview Title</h1>" + divElements + "</td></tr></table>");
  printer.get(0).contentWindow.print();
  printer.remove();

  //Do your things here ...
});
```

[See this JSFiddle for a working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/Zenoo0/373tb7zm/) *(I couldn't do it in a Snippet)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but one issue with this code, when I click on print, and cancel the print preview, its firing print again and again without any click

Comment: @SanjeevKumar It's not firing more than once for me. Could you be more precise?

Comment: I added this code simply but print function is firing after I cancel

Comment: Keep in mind you still have to adapt `$('.test').on("click", ...)` to fit your trigger selector. Add a `console.log()` at the start of the function to see when exactly it is executed multiple times. You might also want to add an ID to your Iframe, and select it by it's ID rather than a class, to avoid some problems if you have multiple Iframes.

Comment: looks like browser was behaving something wrong, but all working fine. thanks! BTW I have updated $(test) .. :)